# How can I format this path to work as registry key value?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, special-characters, escape-characters

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DotR\DotR.exe
```

I know I need to escape the backslashes like `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DotR\\DotR.exe` but it still doesn't work. Do I need to handle spaces and parens as special characters and if so, how?

Edit with details: I'm running a small console application from the context menu. When I save it to C:\DotR.exe and add to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DotR\` the value `C:\\DotR.exe %1` it works fine but when I try to make it `C:\\Program Files(x86)\\DotR\\DotR.exe %1` I get an error message that says application not found. I want to save it in program files and not C root.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How exactly are you trying to add it?

I suspect your primary problem is that you need quotes around the name.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DotR\DotR.exe" %1
```

If you are adding the value by using the `regedit.exe` GUI editor, as a string value, then you do not need to escape the `\` or the `"` characters.  The GUI will handle the escaping, you just need to add the quotes.

If you are adding it with a `.reg` file then it `\` characters do need to be escaped, you also need to escape the " character.  So a REG_SZ value of `"c:\asdf\asdf"` would look like this.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Temp]
"asdf"="\"c:\\asdf\\asdf\""
```