# Registry "Run on Logon" value is running the wrong app

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have an app that I want to set to run on logon, `C:\AutoTests\Auto-Test Executor (Client).exe`. The `C:\AutoTests` directory also contains a file called `Auto-Test Executor.exe`.

I have gone into the registry, and set a value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, `"ClientTestExecutor" = "C:\AutoTests\Auto-Test Executor (Client)"`.

When I log on, the computer automatically runs `Auto-Test Executor.exe`. I have no idea what's going on, its filename comparison seems to be extremely screwy. Do I have any recourse other than changing the filenames to not be so similar?

I have Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the full pathname to the executable (including the file extension) and surround the whole thing in quotes. In other words, your value named `ClientTestExecutor` should contain the data:

```
"C:\AutoTests\Auto-Test Executor (Client).exe"
```

Per this SuperUser [answer](https://superuser.com/a/479110/213131), if you're setting this data through RegEdit, you do not need to escape any of the characters.  However, if you're setting the data with a .reg file, the `\` and `"` characters need to be escaped as shown here:

```
"ClientTestExecutor"="\"C:\\AutoTests\\Auto-Test Executor (Client).exe\""
```